# Looking for Windows macro recorder that can dock its own toolbars in other applications

Tags: windows, macros, toolbar

About 10 years ago there was a Windows macro recorder product that would create custom toolbars that would dock themselves in specific applications under the application's built-in menubar or toolbar.

This allowed one to add custom toolbars to NotePad, WordPad, MS Paint, etc.

Does anyone remember what the name of this product was and if the company is still in business? Or if there are other Windows macro recorders that have the ability to create internally docked toolbars?

My research has found QuickMacros and MacroToolbox both which allow one to create custom toolbars. Unfortunately, these custom toolbars don't look professional and they do not internally dock within an application's existing interface.

Thank you,
Malcolm

Comment: I think the company I'm referring to was based out of Atlanta and the product might have had the word "Smart" in its name?

Comment: I have no idea but if it was based out of Atlanta I might be able to find out - I'm local and know a lot of software devs.  Anything else you can remember would be great.

Comment: Shinrai, Thank you for your help. The product sold in several versions, a user version for $195/$295(?) and a developer version for $495/$695(?). The toolbars this product created had notebook like tabs so you could put a lot of macros and your toolbar by placing similar macros on their own toolbar tab. The product also generated small EXE's that you could distribute to other users.

Comment: autoIT may do something along these lines.

Comment: I wasn't able to turn anything up as of today beyond one guy who vaguely thought he knew what I meant but didn't think they were around anymore.  If I luck out I'll update...I would actually be interested to find this software myself!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to this for a web browser, than iMacros does exactly what you need (but only for web browsers!). It is a free addon for IE, [Firefox](http://www.iopus.com/imacros/firefox/) and Chrome.

Comment: Michael: Not the answer I was looking for, but WOW! what a cool a product. Thank you very much for bringing this product to my attention. We will definitely find a use for this product on other projects.